# Best way to Plot it

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolfram-language

Im trying to Plot the DOS of a infinity linear chain. By the following:

```
s = 10; (*Number of decimation*) 
t = 1;
step = 0.01;
SubStar[E] = w + I*\[Eta];
\[Eta] = 0.01;
\[Epsilon] = 0;


Subscript[\[Beta], 1] = t*1/(SubStar[E] - \[Epsilon])*t;

Subscript[\[Beta], 0] = 1;



For[j = 2, j < s + 1, j++, 
 Subscript[\[Beta], j] = 
  Subscript[\[Beta], j - 1]*1/(SubStar[E] - \[Epsilon] - 2 \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(j - 1\)]
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Beta]\), \(i\)]\))*Subscript[\[Beta], j - 1]];

Subscript[G, 1, 1] = 1/(SubStar[E] - \[Epsilon] - \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \(s\)]
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Beta]\), \(j\)]\));

G22 = (1/(1 - Subscript[G, 1, 1]*Subscript[G, 1, 1]))*Subscript[G, 1, 
   1];

\[Rho] = -1/\[Pi]*Im[G22];
```

I want to plot [Rho] as a w's function.
So, if I let w undefined in the beginning (code above) and plot: 
`ListPlot[Table[{w, \[Rho]}, {w, -2.5, 2.5, step}], Joined -> True, Frame -> True]`
It works well, but its very slow, maybe because the mathematica is doing all the thing algebraically.
If I make w change, like using: w=Range[-2.5,2.5,step], then I can plot something like this:

```
ListPlot[{\[Rho]}, Joined -> True, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Orange]
```

It works pretty faster, but the horizontal axis is not okay in comparison with the previous Plot.

Then, I was thinking in do something like, defining

```
 \[Rho][w]:= Module[{.....},....]
```

And work with this as a function and Plot at the end. 
Any suggestions? What should I do?

Edit1: After the suggestion:

[Comparison between them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rS6x5.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just this?

```
Plot[\[Rho], {w, -2.5, 2.5}, Frame -> True],
```

or better still

```
Plot[\[Rho], {w, -2.5, 2.5}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

Perhaps try this before plotting, but it looks time-consuming.

```
\[Rho] = Simplify[-1/\[Pi]*Im[G22]]
```

I tried this, which was interesting ...

```
For[j = 2, j < s + 1, j++, 
 Print[j];
  Subscript[\[Beta], j] = 
  Simplify[Subscript[\[Beta], 
    j - 1]*1/(SubStar[E] - \[Epsilon] - 2 \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(j - 1\)]
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Beta]\), \(i\)]\))*Subscript[\[Beta], j - 1]]]
```

The 10th iteration is the killer.  It aborted with this message:-

[image]

Comment: I tried this,
.
.
.
\[Rho] = -1/\[Pi]*Im[G22];
\[Micro] = -1/\[Pi]*Im[G11];
\[Zeta] = 1/\[Pi]*Re[G11];

Plot[\[Rho], {w, -2.5, 2.5}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All]

Plot[\[Micro], {w, -2.5, 2.5}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All]

Plot[\[Zeta], {w, -2.5, 2.5}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All]

For \[Rho] worked just well, but for Micro and Zeta, its a little bit slower and some points are missing in plot.

Comment: @LucasLopes Adding the plot option `Exclusions -> None` fills in the missing points and considerably speeds up the Micro and Zeta plots.

Comment: What If I try to vary w in the beginning of the code, it will run faster, but the plot scale is weird...